# Contar número de ocorrências no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Eu tenho uma base de dados onde os valores estão organizados mais ou menos da seguinte forma:

```
id | produto     | data com registro de venda
----------------------------------------------
 1 | Prod1       | 17/09/2019
 2 | Prod1       | 17/09/2019
 3 | Prod2       | 17/09/2019
 4 | Prod2       | 14/09/2019
 5 | Prod1       | 12/09/2019
 6 | Prod1       | 12/09/2019
 7 | Prod1       | 17/09/2019
 8 | Prod1       | 14/09/2019
 9 | Prod3       | 17/09/2019
10 | Prod3       | 17/09/2019
11 | Prod1       | 11/09/2019
12 | Prod1       | 15/09/2019
```

Informação que eu gostaria de obter

```
Prod1 = 5 dias com vendas registradas (ignorando os dias repetidos)
Prod2 = 2 dias com vendas registradas (ignorando os dias repetidos)
Prod3 = 1 dia com vendas registradas (ignorando os dias repetidos)
```

Comment: Mostre o que você ja tentou, se tentou algo e deu erro conte, coloque no corpo da pergunta

Comment: Eu não tentei nada ainda. Eu aprendi apenas a fazer consultas simples. Situações que exigem resultados mais complexos, como é o caso da pergunta, eu ainda não sei como fazer.

Comment: saquei cara. Sabe usar `group by` e funções do `count` e `unique`

Comment: Creio que o que deseja é algo do tipo: SELECT produto, COUNT(DISTINCT data) FROM sua_tabela GROUP BY produto; A documentação do PostgreSQL é muito boa, consulte-a: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/index.html

Comment: @anonimo, isso mesmo cara! Só to na duvida se ele quer com os textos, como está no exemplo de retorno

Comment: Caso ele queira com o texto seria:
SELECT produto, ' = ', COUNT(DISTINCT data), ' dias com vendas registradas (ignorando os dias repetidos)' FROM sua_tabela GROUP BY produto;

Comment: Ontem eu havia conseguido resolver usando o DISTINCT. Obrigado.